# Creating a custom table with a list in django template

Tags: django-templates

I want to create a table like a map displaying the location, weight, and status of paper roll on the warehouse. Location includes lane (A, B, C, D, E) and position (1, 2, 3, ..., 13). Status can be in 4 cases depends on weight of paper roll, I want to display them in different colors:
1. Weight > 700 kgs. --- Green
2. 400 < Weight < 700 kgs. --- Blue
3. 100 < Weight < 400 kgs. --- Yellow
4. 100 < Weight kgs. --- Red

For example, 2 paper rolls of code "AAA111" are located at B-4 and B-9; weigh 300 and 500 kgs respectively. So in the map should display yellow at B-4 and blue at B-9.

I tried to create a table from lists by using "for" tags in template (e.g. inventory.html). Here is related lists including position list (posb), location list (mstr), and weight list (wlist):
posb = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13']
mstr = [(u'B', 4L), (u'B', 9L)]
wlist = [300, 500]

Here are related lines of codes for lane B in inventory.html

```
        {% for pos in posb %}

        {% if pos %}

            {% if "'B', "|add:pos in mstr %}

                {% for wt in wlist %}

                    {% if wt > 700 %}

                        <td class="green">{{ wt }}</td>

                    {% endif %}

                    {% if 400 < wt and wt < 700 %}

                        <td class="blue">{{ wt }}</td>

                    {% endif %}

                    {% if 100 < wt and wt < 400 %}

                        <td class="yellow">{{ wt }}</td>

                    {% endif %}

                    {% if wt < 100 %}

                        <td class="red">{{ wt }}</td>

                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}

                <td class="gray"></td>

            {% endif %}

        {% else %}

            <td></td>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

The problem is this code will create exceeding table cells according to the number of items in wlist. Please see the image following this link: [link text](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_vTKOa8hhS50/TOqR88NZr5I/AAAAAAAAAXg/YzSKGE7sG84/Screenshot.png) (Sorry, my reputation is not enough to post any image)

I have stuck with this problem for a long time. Anyone can help, please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There seems some ineffiency in your if clauses.

Don't you rather mean

```
if 100 >= wt and wt < 400
```

than

```
if 100 < wt and wt < 400
```

(etcetera)?

Comment: I mean that the weight is between 100 and 400 kilograms :)

Comment: Would you mean if wt >= 100 and wt < 400 ? Is it same as if 100 <= wt and wt < 400

Comment: Lol sorry you're right, I was looking wrongly. Still what you wrote is wrong, you should indeed use 'if 100 <= wt and wt < 400' instead of 'if 100 < wt and wt < 400' to cover the case that wt == 100 :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all the logic in the template, it's easier to write a function that handles the logic and then write a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that receives the values and passes them to the function.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of function to handle this problem?

Comment: My actual problem is appearance of double blocks in the map. I cannot pull the value "weight" from the weight list (wlist) at a time and pass into the function. In this case, both values in wlist are passed into the function at a time and it causes double cells two times as you can see in the image I provided.

Comment: So then pass them all as a sequence and let the function look at the maximum or sum as appropriate.

Comment: It is not clear to me. Again please provide me an example. Thank you.